# Realmlist<String> not able to extract it back

Tags: string, realm, realm-java

I am using realm 4.1.1

When trying to use Realmlist in RealmObject we aren't able to retrieve it back

RealmObject data members are as below:

```
@PrimaryKey private String product_id; private String product_name; private String specifications_sheet; private String brochure; private String product_warranty; private String product_description; private String model; private String sku; private String upc; private String quantity; private String image; private String manufacturer_id; private String manufacturer; private String retail_price; private String gold_price; private String trade_price; private String price_currency; private String trade_only; private String products_type; private String category_id; private String category_name; private String subcategory_id; private String subcategory_name; private RealmList<String> images = new RealmList<>();
```

Here when I am trying to do `productDatas.getImages().size()` the size is always coming zero

Please let me know where am I going wrong

Comment: How should anyone answer this if we don't know how the product data is inserted into the Realm?

Comment: Same question with https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5536 . primitive list from json will be released in 4.2.0